# Managing a QEMU guest from the host's CLI

Tags: linux, virtualization, kvm-virtualization, qemu

Can I manage a QEMU guest from the host's CLI? I'm coming from Xen and I liked the `xm` command. I'd like to shutdown the guest, attach PCI devices to it and so on. Is there a way?

There's the QEMU monitor, but I'd really like to have a "scriptable" solution.

Comment: Have a look at [libvirt](http://libvirt.org/).

Comment: Libvirt is good, but it's really a little too bloated for my needs.

Answer (score 3):

[Qemu's QMP](http://wiki.qemu.org/QMP) is probably what you're looking for, but I am not aware of any tools that interface with it yet.  You would have to write a script (or family of scripts) that opens the socket and sends appropriate messages to QEMU.

Comment: Hmm, apparently, QMP is not yet stable.

Comment: Most of QEMU isn't stable yet :-)

Answer (score 0):

any VM management solution out there is based on libvirt nowadays, so `virsh` is the way to go. You don't have to install virt-manager, which drags along a lot of GUI deps